# How do I stop my toggle function at the first and last list items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an unordered list of numbers that scroll. 
The selected/middle list item needs to show in a yellow font color.
I have applied a class toggle function to my scroll buttons. I just need help figuring out a solution that will stop the class toggle function when I get to my first and last list item.

The solution I need must allow for the addition and removal of list items without the need to adjust the JavaScript if possible.

As usual, I know this is light work for you guys.
Any and all help is very much appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="box">
    <ul id="ulscroller">
      <li value="22">&nbsp;</li>
      <li id="1" class="active">1</li>
      <li id="2" class="target">2</li>
      <li id="3" class="active">3</li>
      <li id="4" class="target">4</li>
      <li id="5" class="active">5</li>
      <li value="21" class="lastitem">&nbsp;</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!--Button Controls-->
  <div class="buttholder">
    <a href="#">
      <button class="scrollup">UP</button>
    </a>

    <a href="#">
      <button class="buttok">OK</button>
    </a>

    <a href="#">
      <button class="scroll">Down</button>
    </a>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box li.target {
  color: #fff;
}

.box li.active {
  color: #fada15;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 310px;
  height: 268px;
  background: #000;
}

button {
  width: 72px;
  height: 72px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px
}

#container div {
  position: absolute;
}

ul li {
  font-size: 42px;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: arial;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: 32px;
}

.box {
  border: 0px #00f solid;
  height: 247px;
  width: 199px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#container div.buttholder {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  border: 0px #0f0 solid;
  width: 72px;
  height: 236px;
  top: 11px;
  right: 13px;
}

.lastitem {height: 22px;}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.scroll').click(function() {
    $('li').toggleClass('active', 'target');
    $('.box').animate({
      scrollTop: '+=80'
    }, 100);
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.scrollup').click(function() {
    $('li').toggleClass('active', 'target');
    $('.box').animate({
      scrollTop: '-=80'
    }, 100);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When **[`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)** has two parameters, the second parameter is expected to be a boolean (and not just truthy/falsy).

Therefore, `'target'` is ignored in this code:

```
 $('li').toggleClass('active', 'target');
```

What you could do is set the first `li` as "active," then move the active class to the previous or next `li`, depending on which button is pressed.

If the next `li` is the last child, or the previous `li` is the first child, then don't move the active class.

**Snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.scroll').click(function() {
    var current= $('li.active'),
        next= current.next().not(':last-child');
    
    if(next.length) {
      next.addClass('active');
      current.removeClass('active');
    }
    $('.box').animate({
      scrollTop: '+=80'
    }, 100);
  });

  $('.scrollup').click(function() {
    var current= $('li.active'),
        prev= current.prev().not(':first-child');
    
    if(prev.length) {
      prev.addClass('active');
      current.removeClass('active');
    }
    $('.box').animate({
      scrollTop: '-=80'
    }, 100);
  });
});
```

```css
.box li.target {
  color: #fff;
}
.box li.active {
  color: #fada15;
}
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 310px;
  height: 268px;
  background: #000;
}
button {
  width: 72px;
  height: 72px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px
}
#container div {
  position: absolute;
}
ul li {
  font-size: 42px;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: arial;
  text-align: center;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: 32px;
}
.box {
  border: 0px #00f solid;
  height: 247px;
  width: 199px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#container div.buttholder {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  border: 0px #0f0 solid;
  width: 72px;
  height: 236px;
  top: 11px;
  right: 13px;
}
.lastitem {
  height: 22px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="box">

    <ul id="ulscroller">
      <li value="22">&nbsp;</li>
      <li id="1" class="active">1</li>
      <li id="2">2</li>
      <li id="3">3</li>
      <li id="4">4</li>
      <li id="5">5</li>
      <li value="21" class="lastitem">&nbsp;</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!--Button Controls-->
  <div class="buttholder">
    <a href="#">
      <button class="scrollup">UP</button>
    </a>

    <a href="#">
      <button class="buttok">OK</button>
    </a>

    <a href="#">
      <button class="scroll">Down</button>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Rick!! Thank you so much!!!! Works perfectly!! I appreciate your help so very much!!

Answer (score 1):

## There are two solutions:

### Solution #1

You can use the .first and .last functions of jQuery:

```
$('li').not($('li').first()).not($('li').last())
```

I am choosing all "li" elements,and then remove the first one and the last one.

https://api.jquery.com/last/

---

### Solution #2:

You can also use slice function, like in arrays:

```
$('li').slice(1,-1)
```

This will remove the first and last item in the 'li' array of elements.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: **Solution #3**: Don't use jQuery, learn how javascript works first.

Comment: @Amina I'm sorry. I think I need to reword my question. I need only for the class toggle to stop once I've reached the end of my list. I am unable to get wither of your solutions to work.

Comment: @YourWebGirl I would highly recommend becoming proficient in JS before using the jQuery library.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, again, @JacobGray. With all due respect,  I am always on the path of becoming proficient at JS as well as multiple libraries as I don't always have control over what is used.

Comment: @JacobGray Do you have any resources you could suggest that would help me become better versed in JavaScript? There are a few languages I can code of the top of my head. I can do quite a bit up to a point, but JavaScript has always been my achilles heel. any help or point in the right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Answer of Rick Hitchcock is perfect, however I would just like to add one point. 
For every jQuery function you call, you don't need to encapsulate it in a  `$(document).ready(function()` or `jQuery(document).ready(function($)`. A page manipulation begins only when the page has been loaded. So you don't need to check it twice whether the page has been loaded or not.

Comment: @Amina Yes agreed that is what I meant :: include the entire jQuery snippet in one `$(document).ready(function()` instead of writing `$(document).ready(function()` every time for separate methods.

Comment: @YourWebGirl Most welcome... I am also new to JavaScript and jQuery its been couple of weeks ... I came across your question so decided to answer ...  But may be I am conceptually a bit weak which costed me 2 reputations bt anyws lets see what Amina has to say... :)